# My current office chair makes back ache

Tags: workout-routines, pain, back-pain, lower-back

I know this is probably not a usual question you see on here but anyways. I have over the past year purchased three different office chairs. They have all seemed fine for the first few months, however after the 2-3 month mark my back starts to hurt. There's no specific part, sometimes it's the lower back sometimes the upper back but it keeps me from doing my work properly. I sit at my desk for 8-9 hours a day( I'm a student and software developer).

I'm not sure what to do. Doing back exercises doesn't seem to work either. I don't know whether it's because I'm 197cm tall (~ 6'7'') and most office chairs aren't suited for my height? If so, can you recommend any brand or even a specific chair? It's really a problem for me, it increases my stress levels a lot on top of the pain I have every day in my back.

Any help/suggestions appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if this question is on topic here, as I see no relation to exercise but only a health question (or a shopping recommendation request). Have you talked to a physician?

Comment: I don't see anything related to fitness or exercise as outlined in our [faq]. I'm only reading this a health question (and also shopping recommendation). I think it would be better for you to see some kind of specialist to help. I'm closing this as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a chair that relieves it, try a stand-up or a treadmill desk if possible where you work. I changed over about 18 months ago to a treadmill desk and my back pain has completely disappeared. I would never go back to a chair.